# Missing secret token even if it is set on environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I have generated locally secret key by running this command:

```
rake secret
```

Then in my Ubuntu VPS I have created environment variable like this:

```
echo 'export SECRET_KEY_BASE=<locally_generated_secret_string>' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then I have realoaded my bashrc by running this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

When I type `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` it outputs to me this generated string

Then I have uploaded my rails app via capistrano and launched it. However, logs still shows this error message:

```
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`>
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because there is nowhere in your application where you are setting this yet.

If you check your `config/secrets.yml` file, you will notice that `secret_key_base` has been set for both `development` and `test`, as follow:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: *******...

test:
  secret_key_base: *******...
```

But maybe not for `production`.

What you will need to do then is to add config for `production` environment as well. So, in the `secrets.yml` file, you will have something like:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: *******...

test:
  secret_key_base: *******...

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  secret_token: <%= ENV["SECRET_TOKEN"] %>
```

By setting `secret_key_base` to `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]`, it will be able to get the value which you have exported to your environment, and same goes for `secret_token` as well.

Hope this helps.